# .net bitmap file type limitations

Tags: c#, .net, bitmapdata

Given the line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
```

where stream is a System.IO.Stream, are there any limitations on the image file type e.g png, jpg, gif etc that can be handled.  i.e are all image file/stream header info clear enough to say "I am an image".

I haven't run into any yet, but have only being using the pretty standard ones so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an overview of what is supported:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at62haz6.aspx

All the file types mentioned there are GDI+ which are supported by the .NET framework

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost certain it's the same set as supported by the Bitmap(string) constructor: BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG and TIFF.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Both yours and @jasper's refs got me the answer I wanted so I went to who got there first.  :-( But cheers and a +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

It should work for all image formats for which the OS has a codec available.

Answer (score 0):

Most 3rd party proprietary file formats fail such as `PSD`. `EPS` also fails.

These formats work:

> BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG and TIFF.